# How to use a middleware for a specific route, among other ones?

Tags: http, go, routes, go-chi

My simplified routing is similar to

```
r.Route("/api/v1", func(r chi.Router) {
        r.Route("/case", func(r chi.Router) {
            // generic case - for everyone
            r.Get("/{uuid}", caseGetByUuid)
            r.Put("/", casePut)
            // all cases only available to admins
            // r.Use(ensureAdminUser)  // ← this is the place I have an error
            r.Get("/", caseGetAll)
        }
        // admin endpoint
        r.Route("/admin", func(r chi.Router) {
            // ensure that the user is an admin
            r.Use(ensureAdminUser)
            r.Route("/user", func(r chi.Router) {
                r.Route("/token", func(r chi.Router) { // /admin/user/token
                    r.Get("/", userTokenGetAll)
                    r.Put("/", userTokenCreate)
                    r.Delete("/", userTokenDelete)
                })
            })
        })
    })
```

The **second** route (`/admin`) is restricted by a middleware that will break the chain if specific constraints are not met. The middleware is placed ahead of all the routes.

I wanted to do similar filtering in the **first** route (`/case`), but only for one route (out of the three). Uncommenting `r.Use(ensureAdminUser)` leads to

```
panic: chi: all middlewares must be defined before routes on a mux
```

I cannot have two routes for `/case` either.

**Is there a way to keep the route `/case` and restrict one of the methods for the root call?**

If not I will create an alternative route for the restricted case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the middleware and subsequent routes in their own [group](https://github.com/go-chi/chi#router-interface) (emphasis mine):

> // Group adds a new inline-Router along the current routing
> // path, **with a fresh middleware stack for the inline-Route**.
> `Group(fn func(r Router)) Router`

```
    r.Route("/api/v1", func(r chi.Router) {
        r.Route("/case", func(r chi.Router) {

            // generic case - for everyone
            r.Get("/{uuid}", caseGetByUuid)
            r.Put("/", casePut)

            // all cases only available to admins
            r.Group(func(r chi.Router) {
                r.Use(ensureAdminUser)
                r.Get("/", caseGetAll)
            })
        }
    })
```

It will work also with a sub-router with `r.Route`.

Another option when a middleware is applied to only one route is [`r.With`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-chi/chi#Mux.With) which allows you to “inline” the middleware:

```
r.Route("/api/v1", func(r chi.Router) {
    r.Route("/case", func(r chi.Router) {

        // generic case - for everyone
        r.Get("/{uuid}", caseGetByUuid)
        r.Put("/", casePut)

        // all cases only available to admins
        r.With(ensureAdminUser).Get("/", caseGetAll)
    }
})
```